# What connections do I make to this Through hole DC Power connector

Tags: power, pcb, circuit-design

I'd like to have one of these on a PCB I'm designing but I'm not completely sure how it works. Can somebody please explain to me how to connect this power jack to my circuit?

[image: Through hole power jack]

Comment: You need the datasheet. Not only for the connections but also for the PCB layout as ideally you should use slots, not round holes for the  pins. There are hundreds of these but beware of the size of the plug. If I recall correctly there are three different thicknesses.

Comment: Hi. I’ve had a look at the data sheet and the pins are labeled ‘centre pin,’ ‘sleeve shunt’ and ‘sleeve.’ I’m not really sure what that means, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Centre pin** is, well, the centre pin. Usually this is the positive supply voltage, but sometimes it's earth (ground, 0 V) - you need to check the details of the supply you're going to plug in to it.

**Sleeve** connects to the other contact on the plug - usually earth (ground, 0 V) but sometimes positive supply.

**Sleeve shunt** is probably a spring-loaded contact which connects to the sleeve pin when there is no plug inserted, but is open circuit when a plug is present - this can be used to disconnect an internal power source, for example. Test your connector with a resistance meter though, to check how it actually behaves.